# How to get byobu to run screen instead of tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

With the recently added tmux support, byobu has started running tmux instead of screen. I did not change any settings. It just started using tmux. I would rather use screen. How can I change this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run [byobu-select-backend](http://manpg.es/byobu-select-backend) and select screen to use that as the backend.